# MapView images quality

Tags: android, android-maps, android-mapview

I am using `MapView` in my application, I noticed when I open `Google Maps` or another application like `WeatherBug` and then open my application, the images quality in `Google Maps` is way better. Is there a way to get good quality images through `MapView`? or is it a thing only google can have it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782612/android-mapview-with-high-res-tiles).

Short answer: No, you can't control the quality of the tiles in the `MapView`.

Comment: Thank you, I searched before I put the question but maybe I missed it.