# Why is my google maps v2 map pixelated?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm making an app with Google Maps API V2, but the map appears to be very low quality. When I open the Google Maps app on the same phone, the quality is much higher. Is there some configuration option that I need to set? This is my code:

```
        GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
        options.tiltGesturesEnabled(false);
        options.rotateGesturesEnabled(false);
        mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance(options);
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.map_holder, mapFragment);
        ft.commit();
```

This is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_holder"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/map_pin"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Pixelated Google Maps v2]

Comment: Found my own answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782612/android-mapview-with-high-res-tiles. Just include <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/> in AndroidManifest.xml.